# Функии в Си. Что не так?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define x 100

void output(int t[x][x],int n);
void input(int t[x][x],int n);
void calc(int a[x][x],int b[x][x], int n);

void main(){
    int a[x][x],b[x][x],n;
    printf("n="); scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Matricea este: \n");
    input(a,n);
    printf("Transpusa matricei este: \n");
    calc(a,b,n);
    output(b,n);
}

void output(int t[x][x], int n){
    for(int i=0;i>n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j>n;j++){
            printf("%d",t[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void input(int t[x][x],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&t[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void calc(int a[x][x],int b[x][x], int n){
    int y;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            y=a[j][i];
            b[i][j]=y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это вы нам скажите, что не так. Код не компилируется? Не работает? См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: нет ответа.
Код компилируется, но получаю просто надпись:
"Transpusa matricei este: " , и все(
Я только начал изучать функции в си, и не могу разобраться что я делаю не так. :c

Comment: обратите внимание на 
for(int i=0;i>n;i++)
for(int j=0;j>n;j++)
в 
void output
у Вас i>n, j>n

Comment: даже не знаю что сказать... я тупица))
Спасибо огромное